# How to search for flights not going through Russian airspace?

Tags: air-travel, connecting-flights, flight-search-engines

My flight from Europe to Japan with stop-over in Finland (Helsinki) was cancelled as it went through Russian air space, and no alternative was given.

As far as I know most other flights from London/Paris/Frankfurt also usually fly the northern route through Russian air space.

I am now looking for a different route, southbound, for example with stop-over in Bangkok, or Singapore or United Arab Emirates, or other, doesn't really matter.

How do I best approach such a search that avoids Russian air space?

Comment: Of interest, there is  a difference between actual Russian airspace and and FIRs (Flight information regions) controlled by Russian ATC.  See [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/91995) question on the aviation SE

Comment: You cannot really do that, airlines can and do divert flights based on changing conditions. What's your ultimate goal here? Avoiding Russian air space for your own personal preference or finding a flight that is less likely to be cancelled? One way to make sure would be to fly the other way around, over the US.

Comment: @Relaxed:  Even then, you have to be careful;  the great-circle routes from the Eastern US to East Asia pass through far-eastern Russia as well.

Comment: As both Russia and most other countries have stopped airplanes crossing Russian airspace, it might just be easy, check out which routes are offered for the next few days, then check those to see whether they do fit your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the middle eastern carriers are a good bet at the moment. Etihad, Emirates, Qatar, etc.

A few more options:

1. Thai airways through BKK is another option, but a fair bit of a
   detour.
2. Turkish through Istanbul. Gets close but should stay south of Russia

These are all available for later this week and not particularly  expensive. Air France is offering through Paris as well but that's dicey as the direct route goes straight over Ukraine.

Comment: Ukraine apparently [closed](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-60505415) its airspace, so I doubt that Air France is flying over Ukraine at the moment.  (Also as an aside "*the* Ukraine" is an incorrect designation of the country.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine#Etymology_and_orthography).   I think it also can be perceived as derogatory by Ukrainians)

Comment: Thanks for the hint about naming. Fixed. I know that the airspace is closed and hence I qualified this as the "direct route" being  dicey. It means that they will either reroute or cancel, but it's hard to predict where it will go, I certainly wouldn't book it in the morning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was mostly looking for a way that isn't brute force checking all routes, but that doesn't seem to exist. I eventually found out by checking all flights and their recent routes on flight radar sight that Swiss air diverts all their flights from Zuerich to Tokyo to fly south of Ukraine and Russia.